# Error while mocking fetch requests with Jest: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, typeerror

I'm trying to write test cases for my React application with Jest as the test runner(default create react app config). I'm mocking the methods making my API calls by using **mocks** folder to store a file with methods to return Promises which resolve with API data. My component calls these API-handling methods in an async method with the await keyword. The async/await is wrapped in a try catch. The response from the API method is used to update state. Response comes, and is even seen in a console.log, but the immediate setState after it using this response throws the following error:

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null'

And there's a warning:
'Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.'

Funny thing is I have 5 separate API calls, and all the other 4 get their state updated successfully except this API call.

I have API calls in my code, and this particular Component has 5 API calls. My code structure is such that there is a file called services.js which has methods doing the API calls.

```js
// src/services.js

// A method for making POST calls
export const postData = (url, data) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers
  }).then(fetchErrorHandler);
}

// Method to handle response of the API calls
export const fetchErrorHandler = response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response;
  } else {
    const err = new Error();
    err.status = response.status;
    err.response = response;
    if (response.status === 400) {
      err.body = response.json().then(body => body);
    }
    throw err;
  }
};

// Actual method used for doing this particular API call
export const makeSampleAPICall = () => {
  return postData(URL, formData).then(resp => resp.json());
}
```

And I use it in my components as follows:

```js
  async fetchSomeData() { // This is a bound class method getting called.
    try {
      const response = await makeSampleAPICall();
      const { data } = response;
      this.setState({ previousAnnotations: data });
      } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      }
  }
```

My test case is a simple deep render:

```js
it('deep renders component', () => {
  mount(<MyComponent />);
}
```

And my mock API method:

```js
// src/__mocks__/services.js
export function makeSampleAPICall() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve({
      data: [{ some: 'data' }]
    });
  });
}
```